# Workflow for Turborepo deployment to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, turborepo

I'm using Turborepo that has 2 React Apps

```
apps/web1
apps/web2
```

In Heroku i will have 2 apps also `heroku-web1` and `heroku-web2`.

I have tried using the `https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-buildpack-monorepo.git`
[image]

Even I'm getting this success

```
-----> Monorepo app detected
      Copied apps/web to root of app successfully
```

But getting error `code=H14 desc="No web processes running"` and my understanding this is related to Dino not starting but why? In the web1 app i have script to start `pnpm start`

I'm sure I'm missing something?